# Getter does not consistently retrieve data from Vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I am using a GET request to fetch some data in my database at a particular end-point. However, the data will not display when the application loads. It will, however, display, if I make a change to the code base and the application refreshes through NPM.

When `created()` is called, I am getting `undefined` for my data but actions that push the page to refresh successfully grabs the data that is stashed in `Vuex`

Can someone help me with this inconsistent state?

This is my `index.js` file while is the path `/src/store/modules`

```
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import Vue from 'vue';
import drafters from './modules/drafters';

// Load Vuex
Vue.use(Vuex);

// Create store
export default new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
        drafters
    }
});
```

My `drafters` file

```
// Make requests to our back-end
import axios from 'axios'

const url = 'http://localhost:9000/drafters';

const state = {
    drafters: []
};

const getters = {
    // Get the drafters array
    allDrafters: (state) => state.drafters
};

const actions = {
    async fetchDrafters({ commit }) {
        const response = await axios.get(url)
        commit('setDrafters', response.data)
    }
};

const mutations = {
    setDrafters: (state, drafters) => (state.drafters) = drafters
};

export default {
    state,
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations
};
```

And in my Component...

```
import { mapGetters, mapActions } from 'vuex';

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            currentRound: 0,
            currentPick: 0,
            currentSelector: '',
            timer: null,
            counter: 0,
            drafters: [],
            totalTime: (1 * 60),
            timerCurrentlyRunning: false
        }
    },
    created() {
        this.fetchDrafters();
    },
    computed: mapGetters(['allDrafters']),
    watch: {
        currentPick() {
            this.counter++;
            if (this.currentPick % 12 === 0) {
                this.drafters = this.drafters.reverse();
                this.counter = 0;
                this.currentRound++;

            }
            this.currentSelector = this.drafters[this.counter].name;

        }
    },
    methods: {
        ...mapActions(['fetchDrafters']),
        startTimer() {
            this.timerCurrentlyRunning = true;
            this.timer = setInterval(() => this.countdown(), 1000);
        },
        countdown() {
            if (this.totalTime >= 1) {
                this.totalTime--;
            } else {
                this.totalTime = 0;
                this.resetTimer();
                this.currentPick++;
            }
        },
        padTime(time) {
            return (time < 10 ? '0' : '') + time;
        },
        resetTimer() {
            this.totalTime = (1 * 60);
            clearInterval(this.timer);
            this.timer = null;
            this.startTimer();
        },
        stopTimer() {
            this.timerCurrentlyRunning = false;
            clearInterval(this.timer);
            this.timer = null;
        },
        draftPlayer() {
            this.currentPick++;
        }
    },
    computed: {
        minutes() {
            const minutes = Math.floor(this.totalTime / 60);
            return this.padTime(minutes);
        },
        seconds() {
            const seconds = this.totalTime - (this.minutes * 60);
            return this.padTime(seconds);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try do it with mounted()

Comment: Yeah, same result

Answer (score 0):

You have two `computed` sections in your component. You'll need to combine them, something like:

```js
computed: {
    ...mapGetters(['allDrafters']),
    minutes() {
        const minutes = Math.floor(this.totalTime / 60);
        return this.padTime(minutes);
    },
    seconds() {
        const seconds = this.totalTime - (this.minutes * 60);
        return this.padTime(seconds);
    }
}
```

I suggest using an IDE and/or linter to detect such problems.

Comment: @Darnold14 Having two sections called `computed` will cause one of them to be thrown away. The result will be that any computed properties defined in that section will be ignored, resulting in them being `undefined` when you try to access them. Even if this doesn't totally solve your problem it is really important that you only have a single `computed` section in your component definition. I would expect `allDrafters` to be an empty array inside your `created` hook once you fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your mutation property `setDrafters` is a arrow function that is returning something inconsistent: `(state.drafters) = drafters`, because haven't brackets that is equivalent to write `return`, you should do it with brackets to execute the function body without return nothing, try with:

```
const mutations = {
  setDrafters: (state, drafters) => {
    state.drafters = drafters
  }
};
```

For example in:

```
const getters = {
    // Get the drafters array
    allDrafters: (state) => state.drafters
};
```

There you are returning state.drafters and it's ok, but in the mutation you don't want return value, u want execute the function body to assign.

Comment: Still not giving me the consistent state, unfortunately.